# Ionic not being recognised in gitbash or cmd

Tags: bash, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I use Ionic (1 and 2) daily on a work machine with no issues, but i have come to use it on my home computer and after installing Ionic i get the message :

> bash: ionic: command not found

I have uninstalled and re-installed Node, and done the same with Ionic and GitBash. Here is a screenshot, can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you `echo $PATH` to see if node global bin is in path. Something like `.../node/the_node_version/bin`

Comment: /c/Users/gaz/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/gaz/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/gaz/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/gaz/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Please make sure that in the above location,  **ionic.cmd** is there or not.
If you couldn't find, then un-install all the existing files related to ionic and then re-install.
In the above screenshot, you did not install cordova files. 
In Ionic Docs, you may find this command while getting started:

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Comment: I did this and i cant run cordova command either, im just installing android sdk again but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

to fix this on **windows** you have to set the path to Roaming/npm by this command :

```
npm config set prefix  C:\Users\[windows name folder]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

change windows name folder to yours.
and now install ionic and cordova again

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

..............................................................

if you are on **Linux** you have to change the path to /usr/local

```
npm config set prefix usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

If you face this issue,

uninstall all ionic files & folder from user profile, then install the the ionic & cordova

npm i -g ionic cordova

[Windows]
Once the ionoc & cordova is install then,
Add below PATH in environment variables

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Hope this might help.

I was getting the same issue then i have added the envirnment variable, then it got resolved

Answer (score 0):

**19-10-2019**

Windows 10 pro:

1. Go to `C:\Users\Sampath\.ionic` and then delete all the files there.

**Note:** `Sampath` is my user name

2. `npm install -g ionic`